# Making a counter with a closure in Elixir

Tags: javascript, elixir, closures, immutability

I'm learning Elixir and I just got to the part about closures. When a language has closures, the first thing I usually do is try to make the closure algorithm. In JavaScript it looks something like this:

```
let counter = function() {
    let count = 0;
    return function() {
        count += 1;
        return count;
    };
}();
```

Then, each time that `counter` is called, it will return a new number in sequence.

```
counter(); //  returns 1
counter(); //  returns 2
counter(); //  returns 3
counter(); //  etc.
```

Is it possible to make this in Elixir? The main problem seems to be that `count` would be immutable in Elixir. I could make it a one-element list, but that sounds like a Bad Idea™. What would be the Elixir way of dealing with this purely hypothetical situation?

Answer (score 4):

If you need state, use a [process](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.16/processes.html). In Elixir, the idiomatic ways to do that are with [Agent](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Agent.html) and [GenServer](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html).

The [example](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Agent.html#module-examples) from the Agent docs does exactly as you asked:

```elixir
defmodule Counter do
  use Agent

  def increment do
    Agent.update(__MODULE__, &(&1 + 1))
  end

  # ...
end
```

Usage:

```elixir
Counter.start_link(0)
#=> {:ok, #PID<0.123.0>}

Counter.value()
#=> 0

Counter.increment()
#=> :ok

Counter.increment()
#=> :ok

Counter.value()
#=> 2
```

Answer (score 1):

> The main problem seems to be that `count` would be immutable in Elixir.

```
iex(1)> count = 1
1

iex(2)> IO.puts count
1
:ok

iex(3)> count = 2
2

iex(4)> IO.puts count
2
:ok
```

In elixir, values are immutable, but variables can me made to point to different places in memory where other values are stored.  For example, when the line `count = 2` executes, 2 is stored in memory somewhere, then `count` is bound to that new memory location. After that, no variables are bound to the memory location of 1, so that memory is ready for garbage collection.

Elixir has closures because a function does carry with it the bindings in the environment in which the function was defined, but the bindings are to specific memory locations, and the values at those memory locations are immutable:

```
defmodule A do
  def counter do
    count = 0 

    fn -> 
      count = count + 1
      count
    end

  end

end
```

In iex:

```
iex(6)> c("a.ex")          
[A]

iex(7)> counter = A.counter
#Function<0.55300721/0 in A.counter/0>

iex(8)> counter.()         
1

iex(9)> counter.()
1

iex(10)> counter.()
1
```

> I could make it a one-element list, but that sounds like a Bad Idea™.

...and it wouldn't work.  Lists are an example of how immutable values in memory are advantageous.  When you add a value to the head of a list, elixir creates a whole new list somewhere else in memory.  But, instead of copying the old list to the memory location of the new list, elixir knows that the old list is guaranteed to be immutable, so elixir can just use a pointer to the old list. The new memory location consists of the new elements of the list plus a pointer to the old list--no copying required.  In the case of a closure, the binding would be to the location of the original list in memory, and any changes to the original list would be stored elsewhere in memory.

> What would be the Elixir way of dealing with this purely hypothetical situation?

In elixir/erlang, you can use something called a [GenServer](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/GenServer.html) to preserve state between function calls:

```
defmodule Counter do
  use GenServer

  #Client interface:

  def start_counter(starting_count) do
     GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, starting_count)
  end

  def get_count(pid) do
    GenServer.call(pid, :increment)
  end
  

  # GenServer callback functions:

  @impl true
  def init(starting_count) do
    {:ok, starting_count}
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_call(:increment, _from, current_count) do
    {:reply, current_count, current_count+1} 
  end

end
```

When you write:

```
GenServer.call(pid, :increment)
```

elixir looks for a callback function named `handle_call()` whose first argument matches `:increment` and executes it, passing in the state as the third argument.  You define `handle_call()` to do what you want, then you send a reply back to the calling process and set the new state.

In iex:

```
iex(1)> c("a.ex")                            
[Counter]

iex(2)> {:ok, pid} = Counter.start_counter(1)
{:ok, #PID<0.119.0>}

iex(3)> Counter.get_count(pid)               
1

iex(4)> Counter.get_count(pid)
2

iex(5)> Counter.get_count(pid)
3

iex(6)> Counter.get_count(pid)
4
```

Comment: I just tried to figure it out again for another hour and I got nowhere close. What I'm getting is that Elixir is amazing, but not the best language for that specific problem.

Comment: @eje211, I added some stuff to my answer about closures, I don't know if you got a chance to read it.  `GenServers` are fundamental to elixir/elrang.  They were specifically programmed to handle situations that require preservation of state, like a counter, in an immutable programming paradigm.  The coding behind a GenServer is complex, but the elrang experts did all the work for us, found all the bugs, and gave us a battle tested tool, and now we can use the fruits of their labor very simply.

Comment: In the JavaScript example, the inner variable is completely safe (unless I'm missing something). But, in practice, people wouldn't use a closure. They'd use a JavaScript object, which would be subject to all sorts of race conditions. So while the JavaScript example is simpler and just as safe (I think), that is only true in a very unsafe context. Maybe that's why the more complicated Elixir solution makes sense. I loved Scala, but it was extremely heavy. Elixir is very lightweight. I can't grok it yet, but I'm starting to understand the essence of it, I think.

Comment: I read it again (I've been reading a LOT of Elixir docs today) and, yes, it makes perfect sense now. We never actually see the state. We just get it in a callback, and we send the new state in a function call. That way, nothing has to be mutable. Very clever.